# Where should I point my domain?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, domain

I am making a website (that I am hosting myself) as a proof of concept before I move on to my main project: a private mail server.

### Setup

Machine: My grandma's old tower PC (not very good, I know, but it will do the job)

OS: Standard Ubuntu (not Ubuntu server)

Software: Apache2

Network: my server to my router to my family's router to a modem. The reason for this is that I was trying to move my networking experiments away from my family's WiFi connection.

Domain: I got a domain through .tk Yes I know it isn't the best, but I didn't want to spend money on a experiment that I wasn't sure was going to work. I plan on switching over to .com later.

### Problem

I ran into trouble pointing my domain to my server. I know I have to put in the IP of my server. I also know it has to be the private IP. The problem is, the only IPs I could find for my machine started with 192.168.x.x (the local address) or were generic (255.255.255.0 kinds of things). I know the address is in the format xx.x.xxx.xxx, but the only address I can find in that format is the address for my family's router, which I don't think is right. At the moment I have my domain pointed to my 192.168.x.x address, which I think only works inside my network (haven't had a chance to test it from outside yet).

### What I think might work

I think if I move my router closer to the modem (bypassing out my family's router with a switch), I can use my router's IP and it will work. The only problem is, I don't know how my router will know that all that traffic coming in is supposed to go to my server and not to itself.

### Questions

Did I do this right? If not, would my fix work?

I would rather not post the url because my server doesn't have any security and isn't ready for high traffic (it wouldn't take much to crash it and I haven't learned how to fix it yet), but I can PM it to anyone who needs it.

P.S. The reason I didn't post this in Ask Ubuntu is because it didn't seem to be a purely Ubuntu question. I can move it if deemed necessary.

Comment: You shouldn't configure you website to be accessible outside of your network unless you understand the security ramifications of doing so.  You need to forward the port on the main router to secondary router then forward the port to the server

Comment: "I also know it has to be the private IP". 192.168.x.x **is** the private IP. The public IP is the IP of the router. If you want the website to be accessible to the rest of the Internet, that's the IP you have to point to, and then you need to configure port forwarding on the router to forward port 80 to the private IP.